# Warning after updating mongodb dependency

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've installed the latest version of `winston-mongodb`. I've noticed that the version of `mongodb` from `winston-mongodb` package has updated from `1.6.6` version to `2.0.7` version. After updating I got this `warning`:

> the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options
>   are supported at the top level of the options object
>   [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,connectTimeoutMS,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,promoteLongs,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,keepAliveInitialDelay,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions]

How can I solve this? Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

According to the error message;

`the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object`

so, solution for the problem is simply moving the setting options from the server, replset, socketOptions, mongos and any other hierarchy options up into the top level of the object.

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/db',
  {
    useMongoClient: true,
    server: {
            ssl: true,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 300000,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            },
            auto_reconnect: true,
            reconnectTries: 300000,
            reconnectInterval: 5000
        },
    promiseLibrary: global.Promise
  }
);

change it to;

mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/db',
  {
    useMongoClient: true,
    poolSize: 2,
    ssl: true,
    keepAlive: 300000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectTries: 300000,
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    promiseLibrary: global.Promise
  }
);
```

Hope it helps!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**I noticed this as well.**
It seems that is is a non-fatal bug, as this issue was closed. See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-941 .
I tested with:
mongodb@2.2.24 - gives as you reported warnings!!!
mongodb@2.2.23 - dies with an error.
mongodb@2.2.22 - no warnings and works fine....

**So I would recommend to install verson 2.2.22** for now and see that gives.  That is what I did - since I don't like to see warnings.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may see the following deprecation warning if upgrading from 4.x to 5.x and you didn't use the useMongoClient option in 4.x:

**the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object**

in older version of the MongoDB driver you had to specify distinct options for server connections, replica set connections, and mongos connections:

```
    mongoose.connect(myUri, {
  server: {
    socketOptions: {
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      keepAlive: true
    },
    reconnectTries: 30
  },
  replset: {
    socketOptions: {
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      keepAlive: true
    },
    reconnectTries: 30
  },
  mongos: {
    socketOptions: {
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      keepAlive: true
    },
    reconnectTries: 30
  }
});
```

In mongoose v5.x you can instead declare these options at the top level, without all that extra nesting.

```
// Equivalent to the above code
mongoose.connect(myUri, {
  socketTimeoutMS: 0,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30
});
```

Source: Official Documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html