# Mongoose connect throwing a warning

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am writing a mongodb connected app and while connecting to the server like bellow getting a warning like this:

> Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.

My codes are like bellow

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from './config';
mongoose.connect(config.db.uri);
```

at config.js

```
const config = {
    name: 'API',
    version: '0.0.1',
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    base_url: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
    db: {
        uri: 'mongodb://admin:harry123@127.0.0.1:27017/ai?authSource=admin',
    },
}

export default config;
```

I am using Node v8.0.0 and mongoose 4.10.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a harmless warning and a known mongoose [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5304). See the mongoose thread for details, but as of mongoose 4.10.5, there is no known workaround and it shouldn't affect your application's functionality.

Comment: A sign of relief :D Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The warning is due to the MongoDB driver deprecating the API used by mongoose's default connection logic. As of mongoose 4.11.1 you can opt to use mongo client by setting the `useMongoClient` option, for example

```js
mongoose.connect(config.db.uri, { useMongoClient: true, /* other options */ })
```

Be reminded that using Mongo native client may have unwanted effects, so be sure to test everything out exhaustively
See more details [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Comment: Setting this option causes more issues than it solves for a lot of people.

Comment: Indeed, 4.11.0 is currently unstable

Comment: same issue when using { useMongoClient: true, /* other options */ }

Comment: Issue fixed in 4.11.1

Comment: Fixed in 4.11.2 too

Answer (score 1):

```
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
```

Yes, this is a harmless warning and a known mongoose issue. as said by @
Phu Ngo

So, you can get away with this issue by updating to the latest version of mongoose which is above 4.11.1.

After upgrading the version, this warning may appear if you have used options for connections.

```
he server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,sslCRL,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,connectTimeoutMS,family,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,keepAliveInitialDelay,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions,appname,auth]
```

According to the error message;

```
the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object
```

so, the solution to the problem is simply moving the setting options from the server, replset, socketOptions, mongos and any other hierarchy options up to the top level of the object.

[Solution with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409258/warning-after-updating-mongodb-dependency/47130996#47130996)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem simply by using MongoClient.connect instead of mongoose.connect

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient 

MongoClient.connect(config.uri, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Could NOT connect to database: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to database: ' + config.db);
    }
});
```